# Lastpost.php - Wordpress redirect to last post

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically I want to create a mysite.com/lastpost.php that redirects to the last post made in the website. (Wordpress)

Can someone help me doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll leave debugging to you.

```
<?php
    $last_post = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1
    ) );

    if ( $last_post ) wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( $last_post[0]->ID ) );
?>
```